# SSIS: How to pass a value to variable using SQL-Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am a bit desperated because I cannot find what's wrong in my package:
Have set up a very simple package with only one Execute SQL Task. The only aim is to pass the value 'TestValue' from SQLStatement to a variable 'SourceFolder'.
[Settings Part1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jdIc.png)

[Settings Part2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysBae.png)

Neither an error occurs, nor the variable 'SourceFolder' assignes any value.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Matze

---

Editing via Script-Task/MsgBox works, but the variable grid remains empty

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the result name from SF to 0.  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280492.aspx):

> Some queries that return a single value may not include column names.
>   For example, the statement SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Production.Product
>   returns no column name. You can access the return result using the
>   ordinal position, 0, as the result name. To access the return result
>   by column name, the query must include an AS  clause to
>   provide a column name. The statement SELECT COUNT (*)AS CountOfProduct
>   FROM Production.Product, provides the CountOfProduct column. You can
>   then access the return result column using the CountOfProduct column
>   name or the ordinal position, 0.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Have changed the resultset to 0, it does not help.

Comment: I think I can see what's happening here.  Are you only checking the [variable grid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186902.aspx) for changes to the variable?  If so; this isn't updated at run time.  There are a few ways you can check the value.  One is to drop a [Script Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms141752.aspx) and MsgBox the value.